# Could not find or load main class error when using makefile

Tags: java

I've got a makefile that looks like this. Program with same exact project structure works just fine on intellij and the unix system I'm using yet for some reason this particular main in GameScreen isn't working. Any advice would be appreciated

```
default:cpsc2150/Project3/AbsGameBoard.java cpsc2150/Project3/BoardPosition.jav\
a cpsc2150/Project3/GameBoard.java cpsc2150/Project3/GameScreen.java cpsc2150/P\
roject3/IGameBoard.java cpsc2150/Project3/GameBoardMem.java

        javac cpsc2150/Project3/AbsGameBoard.java cpsc2150/Project3/BoardPositi\
on.java cpsc2150/Project3/GameBoard.java cpsc2150/Project3/GameScreen.java cpsc\
2150/Project3/IGameBoard.java cpsc2150/Project3/GameBoardMem.java

run: cpsc2150/Project3/AbsGameBoard.class cpsc2150/Project3/BoardPosition.class\
 cpsc2150/Project3/GameBoard.class cpsc2150/Project3/GameScreen.class cpsc2150/\
Project3/IGameBoard.class cpsc2150/Project3/GameBoardMem.class

        java cpsc2150/Project3/GameScreen
clean:
        rm cpsc2150/Project3/*.class
```

Heres the start of my GameScreen file as well

```
import java.util.*;
public class GameScreen {
    public GameScreen(){

    }
    //@invariant- xCoord >=0, xCoord <=8, yCoord >=0, yCoord <=0
    //rndNum >=0
    public static void main(String [] args) {
```

Comment: What error(s) do you get when you try `make run`  ?

Comment: Everything compiles just fine, the error I'm getting is Error: Could not find or load main class cpsc2150.Project3.GameScreen

Comment: Thought that might have been it - have a look at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean